# Excel find the median of last 3 number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, median

For example, in the cell `B3` : `=MEDIAN(A1:A3)`, and that formule works all cells from B3 to Bend, but not work for B1 and B2, I tried write `=IFERROR(MEDIAN(A-1,A1),(MEDIAN(A$1,A1))` but the excel not allow nagetive number.

And also why `=MEDIAN("A"&"1:A3")` not work? How can I split `A` and `3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula below would work in B3, B2 and B1 as well as all cell below B3.

```
=MEDIAN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX(ROW()-2,1),1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(),1)))
```

It splits the "A from the 3", as you say, with the ADDRESS function and then converts the result of that to a cell reference using INDIRECT.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! `ADDRESS` function solved lots of problems!